# Why are some classes or methods not "parameter compulsory" in java

Tags: java

Question title can be a little confusing but I didn't have a better way to put to put it.

In Java you can have this:

```
JLabel HoHoHo = new JLabel();
...
HoHoHo.setText("Ho Ho Ho");
```

And this:

```
JLabel HoHoHo = new JLabel("Ho Ho Ho");
```

In both cases, it gives a label with `Ho Ho Ho` on it.

**Question**

How is that possible? I mean, are there to JLabel classes, one with a `String` parameter and one without?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it [fails to demonstrate a minimal understanding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html "constructor overloading introduced and explained in a tutorial for beginners") of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there are 2 *constructors* for the *same* class. The one without parameter just sets the string to a default value (the empty string).

One way to do this would be:

```
public class JLabel extends JComponent{

    private text;

    public JLabel(){
        this("");
    }

    public JLabel(String text){
        this.text=text;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DLJ the actual code for JLabel can be seen at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JLabel.java#JLabel) which shows all the variations of the constructors.

Answer (score 2):

This [JLabel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JLabel.java#JLabel.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) code from openjdk shows that overloaded constructors are used.

```
JLabel() : void
JLabel(String) : void
JLabel(Icon) : void
JLabel(Icon, int) : void
JLabel(String, int) : void
JLabel(String, Icon, int) : void
```

Different forms of the constructor are provided so that you don't have to handle the usual validation. Incase only a single constructor with several parameters was provided by the API e.g. `JLabel(String, Icon, int) : void` you would have to,

- Check number of inputs
- Check if they are syntactically correct

etc